# Customizing my model multiple choice field label doesn't populate with existing values

Tags: django, django-forms

### tl;dr

Custom django form field isn't populating with existing data

### Issue

Hopefully this is a simple problem. I have a form with a custom multiple choice field.

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<b>%s:</b> <span class="context">%s</span>' % (obj.field1, obj.field2))

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    a_field = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
              queryset=MyModel.objects.all(),
              required=False)
```

And this gets me my checkboxes in my template the way I want them, with a `<span>` inside the `<label>`.

However, if this form form has an instance associated with it, the saved values from the model do not check the appropriate boxes. That is, if someone checked box1 and box3, but not box2, it renders all 3 checkboxes as unchecked, even though in the admin I can verify box1 and box3 as checked.

Changing away from my custom choice field to Django's `ModelMultipleChoiceField` gets rid of this problem.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    a_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
              queryset=MyModel.objects.all(),
              required=False)
```

And now in my template box1 and box3 do appear as checked.

**Why is my custom form field not showing existing data?**

Comment: When I try this out, the custom field populates the values OK. Just a thought: is the "a_field" name correct, i.e. the same as the ManyToMany field name (or whatever)? I can reproduce the bug like that.